# Algorithm problem, solving for variables in a dictionary

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, data-structures

Idea of the question is given a dictionary (hash table, this question is language agnostic) of keys and values, where the keys are addresses of either integers or letter variables, substitute all letters for the correct value that they represent. For example,

```
Given: {"a": "12.x.y.3", "x": "4", y: "x.x"}
Output: {"a": "12.4.4.4.3", "x": "4", y: "4.4"}
```

Thinking about the best way to do this. The approach I thought of was iterating over the keys, and each time we encounter a non-integer character, recursing until we reach an 'integer' value.

Would appreciate any other ideas/pseudocode for an efficient approach (time complexity wise).

Answer (score 0):

Build a directed acyclic graph, with each **Key** as a node, and edges from one key to another if first one needs value of second. So in your example there will be below edges:

> (a->x),(a->y),(y->x)

Now [topologically sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) the graph. Which in this case will be `[a,y,x]` i.e. leaf nodes, the ones with integer values will be placed last. Now if you start iterating from end for filling `output` dictionary, you will find for any key all other keys it depends on has already been converted to int. Thus saving you from recursing multiple time for same key.

Or, you know, you could just use dynamic programming to memoize repeated calls :)